# Неправельный роутинг к хосту прописанному в hosts

Tags: сеть, hosts, dns, linux

Здравствуйте. У меня следующая проблема - в hosts прописан ip адрес и имя хоста. Но при попытке пинга по имени пинг идет на другой ip адрес. Кто-то сталкивался с таким? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Файл /etc/nsswitch.conf покажите?

Comment: passwd: compatgroup:  compathosts:  files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dnsnetworks:files dnsservices:filesprotocols:filesrpc:filesethers:filesnetmasks:filesnetgroup:files nispublickey:filesbootparams:filesautomount:files nisaliases:files

Comment: Что за хост ? Покажи hosts

Comment: поменял некоторые роутинги, по пинговал, пингуется по старым адресам, то есть полностью игнорится /etc/hosts

Answer (score 1):

Если unix (linux) - посмотри hosts-файл, нередко из-за лишнего проблема в конце строка игнорируется. Также все интерфейсы перегрузить. Если Windows (7+) и синтаксис hosts-файла правильный - netsh winsock reset && ipconfig /flushdns. Обычно помогало. Также посмотри, что у тебя в маршрутах (unix - netstat -rn, windows - route print)